# How do I change the currency in an Access database?

Tags: microsoft-access, currency-format

I (a British developer) have a database that I am developing for a client in the USA. When I set columns as `currency` they display with a `£` sign. How do I change this so that Access displays a `$` sign for currency fields in this database?

Note that I don't want to change my own regional settings if possible.

Comment: Unless you are also storing what type of currency it is, what does it matter, if it displays as `£` or `$` on your local copy?  If your not willing to change your regional settings then you can't change it locally.

Comment: It also displays as `£` on the client's copy. I had assumed it would respect his settings but apparently not.

Comment: You are 100% the regional settings on the client's machine isn't already correct?  [custom currency symbol in access 2010](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_other/custom-currency-symbol-in-access-2010/7b23a3f1-4206-4865-b9f4-d8d4244b4f70)  [Bing Search](https://www.bing.com/search?q=change+currency+access&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN)

Comment: I'm not 100%, no, but I'd be very surprised if a guy in Michigan who uses Access and Excel regularly has his local currency set to £s. I will check with him though.